# Создать контрол (wpf) для отображения таблицы временных промежутков и событий

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно отобразить временные промежутки с привязанными к ним событиями, содержащими различные данные и состояние. 
Ограничения по технологиям: c#, WPF
Макет выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать стандартный `DataGrid` с привязкой к `DataTable`, у которого в строках лежат кастомные объекты с необходимыми данными, к свойствам которых привязывался в шаблоне `DataGridCellTemplate`. Картинку получаю почти как необходимо, но все очень медленно работает. Особенно на большом количестве столбцов и строк.

Подскажите другие варианты реализации.

Comment: Виртуализацию включили?

Comment: @Discord Если имеете в виду  `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"`, то да, пробовал ставить `Recycling`, к сожалению еще больше тормозит

Comment: У вас много строчек, столбцов или и тех, и других? Виртуализацию обоих включили? Насколько сложные шаблоны? Смотрели, что именно тормозит?

Comment: Строк ожидается несколько десятков, столбцов в пределах количества суток в нескольких месяцах. Виртуализацию включал у всего `DataGrid`, как описал выше `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"`

Comment: @Discord Шаблон `CellTemplate` состоит из `Label` и `Border`. Привязка к свойствам объекта для отображения фона, бордера и текста внутри каждой ячейки.

Тормозит ощутимо вертикальный скроллинг. Горизонтальный двигается без проблем.